# (git) how do I commit/push to the team repo? (entirely different history error)

Tags: git, github, git-push, git-fork, team-project

I am trying to make a commit/push to work on team project.

#### Situation

There is a team project repo at team leader's github.
So I forked the team project repo(I am invited in original team repo).
Then, I cloned the file to my local and added remote branch called '*pjt*' connecting it with my forked repo.
I also added new branch for the commit/push to forked repo is '**nb**'.
I added file using 'git add ', committed it on the '**nb**' branch, then pushed using command

```
git push -u pjt nb
```

#### Problem

But this causes error

```
(forked repo owner name):main and (my ID):nb are entirely different commit histories.
```

[image]

After this happens when I look at my source tree, suddenly the commit history of team project repo appears in my source tree.

How can I make a successful commit/push to my team project repo?

Answer (score 0):

That is not how you contribute to the original of a forked repo.

Instead, you push the new branch to *your* fork. Then, *on GitHub*, you ask for a *pull request* from your new branch in your fork to an existing branch of the original repo. (This is a GitHub feature; you cannot do it thru Git, as it is not a Git feature at all. Git knows nothing of forks or pull requests.)

Alternatively, if you are a fully authorized team member, you do *not* fork at all. You simply clone the team repo to start with and push to it directly (and typically you will then make a pull request at GitHub).